# Python design pattern to validate every user-object interaction

Tags: python, class, validation, oop, design-patterns

I've been working on a python module that implements a base-class for a text-based board game. The class is meant to be used as a "game engine", to be imported by other python programs that define custom user-interfaces to the game.

Each instance of the class represents a game match, with which one can communicate by calling the *appropriate* methods, to register players, enter user actions, change game settings, check the state of the game, etc.

The game logic isn't itself troublesome, but in my efforts to make the class robust I find my code is getting extremely cluttered. The problem is making sure that every interaction with the game is valid, both "structurally":

- that no player is added to the game twice
- that only commands by users that have joined the game are executed.
- that only command issued in the appropriate game stage are executed, etc.

and within the context of the game:

- that the user is referencing valid game-objects
- that the user had the resources available for such a command, etc.

That is, I need to make sure that both the actions of the interface-program and those of the users are valid. Naively making these consistency checks within my class, however, is hiding the the game-logic, and making developing and parsing the code much more burdensome than it should.

I've thought of wrapping the game-class in a validator class that would make the appropriate checks before running each game-class method, thus decoupling the validating part, but was afraid the separation might not be so clean-cut and the code might get too fragmented.

When dealing with attributes, python has great concepts, such as descriptors and the `@property` decorators. Is there something analogous for methods?

I'm sure that's a fairly standard problem, what is the design pattern to help alleviate it?

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean by "wrapping the game-class in a validator class"?

Comment: What I have in mind is dealing purely with the game-logic in the original class, and then having the validator class subclass it. That way, the validator can extend each method of the parent class by first making the appropriate checks, and then running the original method. That way, the game-logic and validating-logic can become (ideally) cleanly separated.
There might be better ways to do it, as this is probably a pretty standard state-of-affairs, and if that's the case I'm all ears

Answer (score 1):

The proxy pattern can be used for this. You put all the checking in the proxy class, and then pass through the functional calls once you've done the auth/data checks. This keeps the implementation of the checks and the game functionality separate.

This example is in Java, but it relates quite well to player entry so you'll get the idea:
https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/proxy/